# Question mark ? is displayed on REST response for i18n

Tags: rest, internationalization

I am stuck with one of problem.

XML and JSON response of REST call don't display correct Chinese or any other foreign language that we we are expecting because post call send other than English language. But Reponse XML or JSON always displayed as question mark.
I tried to Accept-charset,content-language, vary header but i didn't able to get exact language content as response.

POST call url have body part as below
{ 
                "assignmentActivityId": "b1ff695f-1693", 
                "assignmentActivityTitle":"Test", 
                "assignmentActivityType":"INDIVIDUAL", 
                "profileId": "158a1f0a9", 
                "earnedPoints":2, 
               "evaluationComments": "我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体 check 2 19/02/2015", 
                "reviewerComments" : "reviewer ", 
                                  "status": "DRAFT", 
                "documents" : [{"documentUri":"/ContentRepository"}] 
 }

Get call URL should receive evaluationComments of as Chinese but it display ? question mark on response xml or json.

Comment: There was charset problem.

JSP display charset and UTF-8 but DB stored the data on Latin1. So i have change the DB setting for Charset from latin1 to UTF-8. Now working fine all the character are displaying according to internationalization

Answer (score 0):

How do you display it?

If you do a console.log or alert, is it still wrong?
If yes, then it is not a display problem, the response is really damaged.

Mihai

Answer (score 0):

There was charset problem.

JSP display charset and UTF-8 but DB stored the data on Latin1.
So i have change the DB setting for Charset from latin1 to UTF-8.
Now working fine all the character are displaying according to internationalization .